# Wordpress - Overwriting plugin class function

Tags: php, wordpress, class, object, extend

I'm working with a plugin called SEO Ultimate where there is the following class:

```
class SU_Titles extends SU_Module {
    function init() {
        ......
    }
    function change_title_tag($head) {
        ......
    }
    ......
}
```

I want to override the function `change_title_tag` and have managed to override it using the following code:

```
Class SU_Titles_Extended extends SU_Titles
{
    function change_title_tag($head) {

        $title = $this->get_title();
        if (!$title) return $head;
        // Pre-parse the title replacement text to escape the $ ($n backreferences) when followed by a number 0-99 because of preg_replace issue
        $title = preg_replace('/\$(\d)/', '\\\$$1', $title);
        //Replace the old title with the new and return
        $title = do_shortcode($title);
        $title .= "<!--- IF YOU CAN SEE THIS, IT IS WORKING -->";
        return preg_replace('/<title>[^<]*<\/title>/i', '<title>'.$title.'</title>', $head);
    }
}

remove_action( 'after_setup_theme', array( 'SU_Titles', 'change_title_tag' ) );
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', array( 'SU_Titles_Extended', 'change_title_tag' ), 99 );
```

However this causes a **Fatal error**: Using $this when not in object context. (caused on the first line of my override function).

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: the easiest way to make it future proof is to ask the plugin author to add an `apply_filter()` action to the return value of the origional function so you can hook into that. Your problem right now is that you are removing the needed referrence I guess. To make that work you will need to change objects of type `SU_Titles` to objects of type `SU_Tittles_Extended`